# How to know the order of eigen values in PCA

Tags: python, pca

I performed a Pca analysis in python. And, I got the eigenvalues for the analysis, but I don't know what variables of my dataset  are represented in the components. 
There are a way to know which components represent each variable of my data:

for example:  4.669473069609005 corresponds to sillas, etc...

here is the file:
https://storage.googleapis.com/min_ambiente/servi_acc/datos.csv

here is the code:

```
# I have libraries es for some other methods I Implemented here.


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.cloud import bigquery
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from factor_analyzer.factor_analyzer import calculate_bartlett_sphericity
from factor_analyzer.factor_analyzer import calculate_kmo
from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
%matplotlib inline

#load csv
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

data = pd.read_csv("datos.csv") 

data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
a,b = data.shape
X= data.iloc[:,0:b-1]
X.head()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe5EW.png)

```
#####################################################
###Estandarizar y realizar la matriz de covarianza###
#####################################################
#Standardize features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance
#used for generating learning model parameters from training data and
#generate transformed data set
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
mean_vec = np.mean(X_std, axis=0)
cov_mat = (X_std - mean_vec).T.dot((X_std - mean_vec)) / (X_std.shape[0]-1)

###Valores y vectores propios obtenidos de la matriz covarianza
cov_mat = np.cov(X_std.T)
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)

dictionary = dict(zip(lst2, lst1))
print(dictionary)
###print from the highest to the lowest
eig_pairs.sort()
eig_pairs.reverse()


print('eigenvalues in descending order :')
for i in eig_pairs:
    print(i[0])
```

Comment: Eigenvalues don't correspond to single variables.  For each Eigenvalue in `eig_vals`, the corresponding vector in `eig_vecs` is what it corresponds to.

Comment: You should use `numpy.linalg.eigh` as the covariance matrix is hermitian. The eigenvalues will be automatically sorted, and I guess the algorithm should be more efficient. As @MattTimmermans said, each eigenvalue corresponds to an eigenvector in the sense that you are simply performing a decomposition. So, for example, eig_vals[3] corresponds to eig_vecs[:, 3].

Comment: Knowing this, how i correlate those eig_vecs to my original data ?. This is because, want to correlate the output to my data, doing this the analysis will make sense, and i will know which variables are important in my data.